# Crypt32.dll not found for awssdk in .net core running in docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, aws-sdk

I'm running a .NET Core application which utilizes AWSSDK.Core. However, I'm getting an exception when running the following code on Mac or a Docker linux container (`microsoft/dotnet:1.0.1-sdk-projectjson`):

```
ProfileManager.RegisterProfile(_config.Aws.Credentials.ProfileName, _config.Aws.Credentials.AccessKey, _config.Aws.Credentials.Secret);
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Crypt32.dll': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.UserCrypto.CryptProtectData(DATA_BLOB& pDataIn, String szDataDescr, DATA_BLOB& pOptionalEntropy, IntPtr pvReserved, CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT& pPromptStruct, CryptProtectFlags dwFlags, DATA_BLOB& pDataOut)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.UserCrypto.Encrypt(String unencrypted)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.SettingsCollection.ObjectSettings.WriteToJson(JsonWriter writer)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.SettingsCollection.Persist(StreamWriter writer)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Settings.PersistenceManager.saveSettingsType(String type, SettingsCollection settings)
   at Amazon.Util.AWSCredentialsProfile.Persist(String profileName, String accessKeyId, String secretKey)
```

My dependecies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "AWSSDK.Core": "3.3.5"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ProfileManager` is only supported on Windows.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/507#issuecomment-265607037